# How to make an specific XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I do not properly understand the process in making the XMLHttpRequest request.

I want to make an XMLHttpRequest exactly same as the one in the image below. But I do not know how to. Please help.
[image]

Comment: so we can't make this request???????????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fallbacks for each of those like:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
oReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);
```

For reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest